# Docker MySQL no user created

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I need to install some plugins and connect with ssl,I tried to use docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql to initialize mysql.When I connect mysql,it tell me `HOST '172.16.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL Server.`  Then I use `skip-grant-tables` to check user table,there is no user in my mysql.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql:5.7

ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD Q123#@!

ENV AUTO_RUN_DIR /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ENV MYSQL_LOG_DIR /var/log

COPY init.d/* $AUTO_RUN_DIR/
RUN chmod a+x -R $AUTO_RUN_DIR/*

RUN mkdir -p $MYSQL_LOG_DIR
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql $MYSQL_LOG_DIR
RUN echo "" >> $MYSQL_LOG/mysql.err

RUN mkdir -p /opt/mysql/ssl
COPY ./lib/* /opt/mysql/ssl/
RUN chmod 600 /opt/mysql/ssl/*.pem
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /opt/mysql/ssl/*.pem

EXPOSE 3306

VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql","/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d"]
```

init.d/init.sql:

```
INSTALL PLUGIN validate_password SONAME 'validate_password.so';
INSTALL PLUGIN connection_control SONAME 'connection_control.so';
set global validate_password_check_user_name=OFF;
set global validate_password_length=8;
set global validate_password_mixed_case_count=1;
set global validate_password_number_count=1;
set global validate_password_policy=1;
set global validate_password_special_char_count=1
DROP USER 'root'@'%'
DROP USER 'root'@'localhost'
flush privileges;
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' identified by 'Q123#@!';
flush privileges;
alter USER 'root'@'%' require ssl;
flush privileges;
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
  mysql:
    container_name: test-mysql
    build:
      context: ./test/mysql
    image: test-mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3360:3306"
    command: ['mysqld', '--character-set-server=utf8mb4', '--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp']
    volumes:
      - /data/mysql-test/:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./test/mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d
      - ./test/mysql/init.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Q123#@!
    networks:
      - laravel
```

Comment: validate_password  plugin maybe the key of this question.